# using pipelines with a local model

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use a simple `pipeline` offline. I am only allowed to download files directly from the web.

I went to https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english/tree/main and downloaded all the files in a local folder `C:\\Users\\me\\mymodel`

However, when I tried to load the model I get a strange error

```
from transformers import pipeline

classifier = pipeline(task= 'sentiment-analysis', 
                      model= "C:\\Users\\me\\mymodel",
                      tokenizer = "C:\\Users\\me\\mymodel")

ValueError: unable to parse C:\Users\me\mymodel\modelcard.json as a URL or as a local path
```

What is the issue here?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you list the contents of that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution was slightly indirect:

1. load the model on a computer with internet access
2. save the model with `save_pretrained()`
3. transfer the folder obtained above to the offline machine and point its path in the `pipeline` call

The folder will contain all the expected files.

Answer (score 1):

Must be either of the two cases:

- You didn't download all the required files properly
- Folder path is wrong

FYI, I am listing out the required contents in the directory:

- config.json
- pytorch_model.bin/ tf_model.h5
- special_tokens_map.json
- tokenizer.json
- tokenizer_config.json
- vocab.txt

Comment: hello! thanks, well I simply downloaded all the files listed in the url above. Note, I  am using tensor flow so its tf_model.h5 instead of pytorch_model.bin. I dont see a special token map.json for instance

Comment: Did it work finally? Not sure why you mentioned `map.json`, please elaborate